# How do you pronounce "exegesis"?

Tags: pronunciation

I'm getting confusing results from dictionaries.

Would you mind uploading or linking to a recording of the correct pronunciation -- perhaps you would record yourself saying it, both isolated and in a sentence?

**Edit**

Does it rhyme with *nemesis*?

Comment: The OED has **Brit. /ˌɛksᵻˈdʒiːsɪs/,  U.S. /ˌɛksəˈdʒisᵻs/** which accords with how I would say it.

Comment: @1006a - Could you say explicitly which syllable gets the stress, please (1, 2, or 3)?

Comment: Secondary stress on the first syllable, primary stress on the third syllable. The secondary is pretty strong, though, almost as strong as primary.

Comment: "ex-eh-jee'-sus" in AmE. Does not rhyme with nemesis "nem'-eh-sis."

Comment: Does someone want to post an answer or should I delete the question?

Comment: You are allowed (and encouraged) to post your own answer, linking to the sources you have checked.

Comment: Here is a YouTube audio pronunciation guide (although the speaker puts slightly less emphasis on the third syllable than I do): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ahb8bSF6E2Q I also agree with 1006a's comment, above.

Comment: Suggestion: If you Google "How do you pronounce 'word-in-question'?" you'll find audio clips for almost any word in the English language. I use it whenever I am unsure of my own pronunciation.

Comment: "Acts of Jesus"

Comment: @sumelic - I think what happened was that some of the dictionaries I looked at put the little symbol showing which syllable gets the stress right before the stressed syllable, but I hadn't understood that.  I was used to a different system, where the stressed syllable gets indicated by placing the little symbol right after. // I'm fine with deleting the question.  // I'm rather disappointed in the pronunciation of this word.  I was hoping the second syllable would get the stress.

Comment: @sumelic - aesthetics, I guess.  Sometimes you get the wrong idea about the pronunciation of a word, when you're reading and guessing at what a new word means from the context, and it can be hard to let go of your first guess at the pronunciation.  One of my children tyrannically insists on pronouncing *tyranny* with a long i, for example.  (Like *tyrant*.)

Comment: @sumelic - I'm interested in your idea.  But I don't quite get it yet.  I see two identical looking vowels there: e with a bar over it.  Are the long and short versions of E the same in Greek as in German?  (For example, the first syllable of *Kreme* is long, but the E in *Mensch* is short.)

Comment: German is similar in the sense of having a length system, but as far as we can tell the vowel qualities of long and short e in Ancient Greek were reversed compared to German. I.E. Ancient Greek epsilon (ε) sounded like a *short* version of the German vowel in *Kreme,* while eta (η) sounded like a *long* version of the German vowel in *Mensch* (or like the long vowel in *Käse* for speakers who distinguish that from the vowel in *Kreme* or *lese*). The stress assignment rule used in English for words from Greek is actually taken from Latin...

Comment: @sumelic - this is intriguing but I'm not getting it.

Comment: I think it sometimes gets confused with *exengency*. I've heard things like eggs edge e sis.

Comment: @PhilSweet - I looked up your word and only found exigency.  I don't think that's what you meant, because the stress in *exigency* seems to be on the first syllable.  Can you provide a link, please? // So in "eggs edge e sis" the stress is on which syllable?

Comment: @aparente001 Yes, I meant exigency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Exegesis* is pronounced /ˌɛksɪˈdʒiːsɪs/ or  /ˌɛksəˈdʒiːsɪs/ (or possibly /ˌɛksəˈdʒiːsəs/), with primary stress on the second-to-last syllable. More or less: ek-sih-**JEE**-sis.
It rhymes with *thesis,* for most people (not for the ones who say "thessis", which apparently some people do). I think the pronunciation on [Forvo](https://forvo.com/search/exegesis/) sounds correct.

There is an explanation (of sorts) for why it is stressed on the second-to-last syllable, unlike *nemesis.*

“Exegesis” comes from the (ancient) Greek word *ἐξήγησις*. The English language has had very little direct contact with Greek. Most Greek-derived words in English were either taken from Latin, or were taken from Greek by scholars but treated “as if” they were passed through Latin. For example, Greek kappa (κ) corresponds most directly in form and sound to English “k”, but Greek-derived words usually have “c” instead because that was the letter that was regularly used in Latin to transliterate Greek “κ”.

This Latinization of Greek loans extends to stress patterns. Greek has its own stress system, but in general this is irrelevant to the pronunciation of an English word that is taken from Classical Greek. Instead, most loanwords like this conform to Latin stress patterns.

In Latin, the position of the stress in a polysyllabic word was, in general, entirely determined by the sounds and syllable structure of the second-to-last syllable.

The relevant rule in this case is that if the second-to-last syllable contained a long vowel, it was stressed.

The word *ἐξήγησις* can be transliterated as *exēgēsis.* The symbol *ē* represents the Greek “long e” vowel (thought to have been pronounced as something like an extended version of the vowel in English “bed”). Because the second-to-last syllable of *exēgēsis* contains a long vowel, it would have been stressed on this syllable in Latin. And this is the source of the stress pattern of this word in English.

The word "nemesis", on the other hand, comes from Greek *νέμεσις nemesis,* with a short vowel in the second-to-last syllable. In words with a “short” second-to-last syllable like this, the Latin stress rule regularly places the stress on the third-to-last syllable.

Hopefully this explanation is clear enough. As with many explanations relating to English pronunciation, it has exceptions. Some words, like *plethora* from Greek *πληθώρα/πληθώρη* and *metamorphosis* from *μεταμόρϕωσις*, are pronounced differently from how we’d expect from the Latin stress rules. (In general, at least—the OED does record an alternate pronunciation of *metamorphosis* with stress on the second-to-last syllable, although it doesn’t seem to be common.)

Examples where the Latin stress rule holds:

- Stressed on second-to-last syllable because it had a long vowel: *oecesis, kinesis, mimesis, noesis, cyesis, ketosis, osmosis, xerosis, zygosis, meiosis, ptosis.*
- Stressed on third-to-last syllable because the second-to-last syllable was "short": *genesis, emesis, ectasis, entasis, epitasis, protasis, di(a)eresis, syn(a)eresis, paresis, telesis, paralysis, hypothesis, aphesis.*

Comment: The part about long and short vowels in Greek was confusing, but it's not your fault.  Overall, great answer, thanks.